# SQlite Data on selection not present showing though data is inserted

Tags: android, sqlite

public boolean checkWhetherDataPresentorNot(String question_id, String selected_option, String session_id) {

```
    Log.d(" CHECKDATA ", "Question Id" + question_id);
    Log.d("CHECKDATA ", "Selected_option " + selected_option);
    Log.d("CHECKDATA", "Session ID " + session_id);

    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TEST_START, new String [] {QUESTION_ID_TEST_START, SELECTED_OPTION_TEST_START,TEST_START_ID}, "question_id_test_start = ? AND selected_option_test_start = ? AND test_start_id = ?",
            new String[] { question_id, selected_option, session_id },
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("CHECKDATA ", "DATA IS PRESENT");
        return true;
    }else{
        Log.d("CHECKDATA ","DATA NOT PRESENT");
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you need to do more describing and explaining. What do you observe? What do you expect? ...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Actually i am able to insert the data into database but not able to check wheather data present or not. Though data is insert it should return true but it is showning not present

Comment: Please [edit] to add that useful information - and much more.